# php script is not receiving data param of Javascript load() method

Tags: javascript, php, html

thank you in advance for your help on this matter.  I'm trying to implement a dynamic drop down menu.  The region menu is created dynamically upon a selection of a country.  The problem is that the country value is not reaching the php script, and so I am unable to create the proper sql statment.  I have used a "select col from table" query to verify the dynamic list is indeed being created (just not one based on user's country selection).  I am not sure why the "choice" isn't making it over.  I'm thinking it may be a problem with my javascript syntax?  Any guidance is much appreciated!

FILE: cargo.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#product_country").click(function()
     {
         $("#product_region").load("../scripts/find_region.php?choice=" + $("#product_country").val());
     });
});
```

html of cargo.php

```
 <table id="menuSelectors" width="850" cellpadding="2">
 <form action="cargo.php" method="POST">
  <tr>
    <td>varietal</td>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>style</td>
    <td>color</td>
    <td>country</td>
    <td>region</td>
    <td>price</td>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="product_varietal" class="selector">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="merlot">merlot</option>
        <option value="pinot gris">pinot gris</option>
        <option value="chardonnay">chardonnay</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <select name="product_type" class="selector">
          <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
          <option value="sparkling">sparkling</option>
          <option value="still">still</option>
          <option value="still">effervescent</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <select name="product_style" class="selector"> 
          <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
          <option value="dry">dry</option>
          <option value="sweet">sweet</option>
          <option value="semi-sweet">semi-sweet</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="product_color" class="selector">
          <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
          <option value="red">red</option>
          <option value="white">white</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="product_country" name="product_country" class="selector">
          <option value="australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="france">France</option>
          <option value="germany">Germany</option>
          <option value="united states">United States</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="product_region" name="product_region" class="selector">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country First</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="product_price" class="selector">
          <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
          <option value="BETWEEN 0 AND 10"> under $10</option>
          <option value="BETWEEN 10 AND 20">$10 - $20</option>
          <option value="BETWEEN 20 AND 30">$20 - $30</option>
          <option value="BETWEEN 40 AND 50">$40 - $50</option>
          <option value="BETWEEN 50 AND 100">$50 - $100</option>
          <option value="BETWEEN 100 AND 500">$100 over</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></td>
  </tr>
 </form>
</table>
```

File: find_region.php

```
<?php
    //CONNECT
    require_once 'connect.php';


    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

    $region_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT product_region FROM product");
    //$region_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT wine_region FROM wine_regions WHERE wine_country = '$country'");

    if (!$region_result) 
    {
       printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    }
    else
    {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($region_result)) 
        {
            echo "<option>" . $row{'product_region'} . "</option>";
        //echo "<option>" . $row{'wine_region'} . "</option>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Try `$("#product_country").change()` instead of `$("#product_country").click()`?

Comment: Also, having the PHP script return HTML is bad practice... consider returning JSON data and interpreting it (to HTML etc.) using Javascript.

Comment: What happens when you type the URL ../scripts/find_region.php?choice=foo into your browser?  In other words are you sure the PHP is working correctly?

Comment: Thank you Chris Willard!  The problem was: mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);  I needed to add $con param before the $GET param.

Comment: review the path : ../scripts/find_region.php    if is correct.